# General way to group objects by several properties in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections, grouping

I have a collection of items:

```
class Item {        
    String type;
    boolean flag;
    int size;
    ...
}
```

There are a few possible types (say "a", "b" and "c") and therefore several possible combinations of type-flag values (`["a" ; false], ["a" ; true"], ["b" ; false]`, ... ). I need to collapse items that have same combination of values, so I have `collapse` method with this signature

```
Item collapse(Collection<Item> items)
```

What I need is to divide input items list into groups that have same `type` and `flag` values

```
List<Collection<Item>> getGroups(Collection<Item> items) // method I need
```

so I could collapse each group

```
List<Item> r = getGroups(items).stream().map(Item::collapse).collect(toList());
```

So I could create a Map of Maps or make some composite keys, but it requires some boilerplate code which I'd like to avoid. In future I can have more attributes for grouping, so the solution should not be hardcoded on these two properties, but be easily extendable for new ones.

How can this be done nicely? Is there a well-known solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Item(1, true, 1));
    list.add(new Item(1, true, 2));

    list.add(new Item(1, false, 3));
    list.add(new Item(1, false, 4));

    list.add(new Item(2, true, 5));
    list.add(new Item(2, false, 6));

    Collection<List<Item>> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Arrays.<Object>asList(x.keyA, x.keyB)))
            .values();

    for (List<Item> items : result) {
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}

static class Item {
    Integer keyA;
    Boolean keyB;
    Integer value;

    public Item(Integer keyA, Boolean keyB, Integer value) {
        this.keyA = keyA;
        this.keyB = keyB;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "keyA=" + keyA +
                ", keyB=" + keyB +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat! Looks like I have to dig into the Java SE 8 API to get up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

In order to know which `Item` logically equals some other `Item` for collapsing, I'd put the responsibility of that on the `Item` class itself. You could override the `equals` method, but if you're gonna put them in a `Set` somewhere this might lead to undesirable results, so a separate method used for checking might be best.

Another option is to take those fields that would be used for this check and turn them into an inner class of `Item`. `equals` and `hashCode` could then be overridden for the inner class only and its instances used as a key for a `Map`.

None of this is going to automagically include any new fields you add later, however. So it'll be up to whoever maintains the class to make sure anything that needs to be included in the check (or equals/hashCode) is added to the method(s).

The only way I can really think of to get close to this is to use reflection. If anything that must be taken into account is only put in an inner class, that would work. If you must keep it on the `Item` class directly, perhaps defining an annotation (with runtime retention) could be useful. The code doing the checking (or equals/hashCode if used) could reflect upon the class and use every annotated field.

The annotation could look something like this:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CollapseField {

}
```

And then used like this:

```
class Item {      
    @CollapseField  
    String type;
    @CollapseField
    boolean flag;
    int size;
    ...
}
```

The code using it would then need to check which fields are annotated and get their values (both of these actions using reflection) and check equality with other objects to establish which belong together. Since this might impact performance quite a bit, using caching for something like a hash code would be a good idea.

In the end, I'm not sure if it's worth it over hard-coding the used values unless you're gonna use this in a large amount of classes or the number of fields could become quite large.

Finally, it may seem odd for Java, but perhaps using the properties pattern instead of fields may make sense. Although you'll lose some type safety. Steve Yegge made a long but interesting post about it: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.be/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html

That's pretty much all I can come up with off the top of my head. As far as I know, there is no standard approach. Maybe someone knows of some convenient library offering a solution.

EDIT: here's an example where the fields to be used for the key are made into an inner class, which implements `equals` and `hashCode` so it can be used as the key for a `Map`:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Item {

    int size;
    final Key key;

    public class Key {

        String type;
        boolean flag;

        public Key(String type, boolean flag) {
            this.type = type;
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public boolean isFlag() {
            return flag;
        }

        public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 5;
            hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.type);
            hash = 89 * hash + (this.flag ? 1 : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Key other = (Key) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.type, other.type)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.flag != other.flag) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    public Item(String type, boolean flag, int size) {
        key = new Key(type, flag);
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return key.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.key.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return key.flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.key.flag = flag;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

}
```

The getters and setters on the `Item` level delegate some of the fields to the `Key`. Note that the getters and setters in `Key` might not be necessary if you're only going through `Item`, since the fields are directly accessible to the containing class. If you need to add a field that must be part of the key, add it to `Key`. If it must not be used for identification, add it directly to `Item`. `equals` and `hashCode` can be easily auto-generated by any decent IDE if you must update them.

Do note that this solution might break if you use the class in some framework that does reflection or introspection. Depending on how it's approached, the fields in `Key` might end up being seen as properties of `Item` (due to the getters/setters) or not. Something like JPA or an EJB container approaching fields directly via reflection could fail to work with this.

Comment: ummm, this looks over engineered, especially the reflection part

Comment: That's Java for you, my friend. In the absence of more powerful language and metaprogramming facilities, weird overengineered patterns start popping up. It's why there's such a ridiculous amount of factories and abstract factories and who knows what else all throughout the Java API and frameworks.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget, definitely the primary cause for such vast amounts of boilerplate. Maybe look into Project Lombok to make things less painful. I'm not sure it's gonna help you with this case, but it might (easy generation of equals/hashCode with one annotation).

Comment: I added my current version as a starting point, it looks much simpler, though I do not like the conversion of everything to strings

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I've edited my answer to add an example of using an inner class. It avoids having to use String concatenation to create the Map key.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker user3707125's answer is obviously the much better one. It's actually an illustration of what I mentioned: not having used Java lambdas yet, I'm reaching for solutions with existing methods. But the introduction of lambdas in Java 8 makes some of those things redundant because the right facilities now exist.

Answer (score 0):

Putting here my current approach with composite key, but still waiting for fresh ideas

```
Collection<Collection<Item>> getGroups(Collection<Item> items) {
    Map<String, Collection<Item>> itemsByKey = new HashMap<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        String key = item.key();
        Collection<Item> byKey = itemsByKey.get(key);
        if (byKey == null) {
            itemsByKey.put(key, (byKey = new ArrayList<>()));
        }
        byKey.add(item);
    }
    return itemsByKey.values();
}

class Item {
    public String key() { type + "-" + flag }
```

New fields can be added easily, but string keys do not look great.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue of having to hard-code the used fields, though. Other than that, I don't see a problem with using Strings as keys. Unless your `type` can contain the separator used it should work fine, equality and hashCode checks for Strings work well and it's done very frequently in Maps. Maybe try optimizing a bit by constructing the key value once and then caching it. Since the key might be used frequently, having it constructed every time you call `key()` is wasteful. I believe the String implementation probably caches its hash code too.